# ShareActionProvider not working without shareIntent being ready

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

In my app, I have an option of sharing images from the `GridView`. Currently, when the Share menu is selected, I prepare a `shareIntent` that contains Uris for all of the selected images and then call the `Intent.createChooser()`.

I'd like to use **ShareActionProvider**, but in order for the Share menu item to be clickable, when backed up by the **ShareActionProvider**, the `shareIntent` has to be specified.

How can I specify the shareIntent inside `onCreateOptionsMenu()` if I don't know which images will be chosen? I would expect to prepare the shareIntent inside the `onOptionsItemSelected()` function.

As a side note, I am doing this from a Fragment and not from an Activity, does it make a difference?

Thank You,

Gary